# Architecting a solution to reduce memory of a complex OR/AND Query with MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, architecture

We currently have a large database running on MongoDB. Our permissions system is sophisticated and we allow our clients to post their queries to our API and we then 'augment' the user's query to ensure that they can't retrieve any records they don't have access to.

The permissions include a combination of accounts, folders, authors and owners,
each document in the collection has the following properties:

- A single 'account' field
- A single 'author' id
- A single 'privacy' property that can be set to 'public'
- An array of multiple 'folder' ids
- An array of multiple 'owner' ids

The queries retrieve items items that
 1. Match the user submitted criteria Eg. all 'posts' that are 'published' in category
 2. AND either the item is be marked as public
 OR match at least one of the following:

```
- The item must be in the same account as the user
- OR in a shared account and marked as 'shared'
- OR in a folder the user is allowed to access 
- OR the user is an owner of the item and the item is in a folder the user is granted access to 'view owned' posts
- OR the user is not an owner but the item is in a folder the user is to granted access to'view any' post
```

A typical entry in the database looks like this

```
var record = {
    "_id":"5a24bad3fbdd2d5b98adcee0",
    "author":"587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919",
    "folders":[
        "5a24bad3fbdd2d5b98adcee0",
        "56b95797a4b114fb7f1259ae",
        "569c7ffb2c0c5259249ecf28"
    ],
    "owners":["587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919", "587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919"]
}
```

A typical query might look like this

```
var queryCriteria = {

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    //The item must be in one of these IDs
    //(Example original query submitted by the user)
    "_id": {
        "$in": [
            "5a24bad3fbdd2d5b98adcee0",
            "56b95797a4b114fb7f1259ae",
            "569c7ffb2c0c5259249ecf28",
            "56b95797a4b114fb7f1259ae",
            "5d3e310b54b3986fe5d17181",
            "5ce5fc28c039b52783601f9b"
        ]
    },
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    //And match at least one of these conditions
    "$or": [
        //The item is public
        {
            "privacy": "public"
        }, 

        //Or the item is matches one of the following combinations
        {
            "$and": [
                //Must match all of these conditions
                {
                    "$or": [

                        //The item is in one of the following folders and the user is listed as the author
                        {
                            "author": "587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919",
                            "folders": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919",
                                    "56097bf03beca073d470de61"
                                ]
                            }
                        },

                        //The item is in one of the following folders and the user is listed as an owner
                        {
                            "owner": "587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919",
                            "folders": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "587c1dccn339ba5ae1cf6919",
                                    "56097bf03beca073d470de61"
                                ]
                            }
                        },

                        //The item is in one of the following folders
                        {
                            "folders": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "687c1dccn229ba3ae1cf6919",
                                    "66097bf03aeca083d470de61"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "$or": [
                        //The item is in the user's account
                        {
                            "account": "5679f95dce092932344f37bb",

                        },

                        //The item is in a user's parent account and as marked as inheritable
                        {
                            "account": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "54ebd2553a6e88a31bb68538",
                                    "5703119feffc46c514119182",
                                    "587c1daaa339ba5ae1cf68fb",
                                    "5703199feffc46c51411d98a",
                                    "59097b723beca073d470dbfa",
                                    "5758d306da9582f20fd8a62e"
                                ]
                            },
                            "shared": true
                        },

                        //The item is in one of a user's parent accounts and is in a folder that is inheritable
                        {
                            "account": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "54ebd2553a6e88a31bb68538",
                                    "5703119feffc46c514119182",
                                    "587c1daaa339ba5ae1cf68fb",
                                    "5703199feffc46c51411d98a",
                                    "59097b723beca073d470dbfa",
                                    "5758d306da9582f20fd8a62e"
                                ]
                            },
                            "folders": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "587c1dcca339ba5ae1cf6919",
                                    "59097bf03beca073d470de61"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "privacy": "public"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
}
```

When querying the database, MongoDB requires a lot of memory to run through all of the $and/$or checks for each document, this is of concern and often causes OOM condition on the database resulting in downtime.

Comment: We cannot really tell you which way is faster, you will probably have to measure it, I don't like either though. I also feel your permission system is overly complicated, you may want to look into reimplementing it (as it seems to be a significant part of your business logic). My first idea would be to do encode all permissions as folders. E.g. marking a document as "shared" adds a (dummy) folder to the "folders"-array, and all users have this folder in their permission list. Then you only need to check "author" and "folders", against that list, both available at the document, and indexed(?).

Comment: Also, your augmentation system itself will probably be a significant part of the problem/slowness, e.g. the trivial solution of simply adding an `and id in <permission check query or list>` to every single `where` will probably be slow (and just filtering the resultset is prone to side channel attacks), so optimizing here might be another option to boost performance. In general though, I think your question is too broad/unspecific to be answerable. Maybe you can try a specific solution, then ask about optimizing this path, not sure if that is viable though.

Comment: @Solarflare thank you for your response, the permission system is complicated but it has to be for privacy reasons. I will work on architecting some other solutions and post questions around those proposals